# How to set eom byte in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I am load testing a tcp server in jmeter in gui mode and getting this error

[image]

I read about adding end of line byte but my data kind of has 2 bytes as ending message byte = "0d0a"

How can I use BinaryTCPClientImpl class and set this eombyte?

2) I have always used the gui mode, do I have to extend the BinaryTCPClientImpl class to set the eombyte?

Comment: 0d0a looks like hexa presentation of newline. Did you try to simply add newline after your data (i.e: press Enter in Text to send field after your data)?

Comment: it did work, but I didn't understand the logic that if 0a is present anywhere between the data, wouldn't it stop reading?

Comment: it depends on logic of your tcp server, so great question for developers.

Comment: or you can actually test it yourself by having newline somewhere in the middle

Comment: The logics works correctly for any newline inserted in between, I mean it reads till the last newline!